# Oracle APEX default value not working on cascaded items

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a blank page with a static content region (Template = Form Region). I select a project via a select list (there is only one project, so it automatically selects it). I then have a key popup lov (a popup lov that displays the description not the returned number value) from which I select a person to be in this project. I am trying to get the form to display the person I selected and saved previously when the form launches for the first time (since the project is chosen due to there being one). This works when you refresh the page, but it doesn't work if you log out and log back into the form. I tried using the default value with a sql query. I tried using a dynamic action that fires when the project changes; but neither approaches work. I fiddled with all the settings, but couldn't get anything to work. Does anyone know how to accomplish this in Oracle APEX?

I even added a refresh of the cascading popup lov to the dynamic action. I can see the hidden input item showing my defaulted value, but the popup lov does not display it on screen. Is this an Oracle bug?

Also in Javascript from the console

```
$s("P51_LINE_MANAGER1", "7104");
```

sets the hidden value, but doesn't display on screen.

```
$v("P51_LINE_MANAGER1");
```

does however return 7104.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly.  Are you saying you want APEX to remember the last value the user selected into P51_LINE_MANAGER after they log off and on again?

Comment: If so you could use a User Preference.

Comment: I want a sql statement to populate the default value, which works if you refresh the page; but doesn't work if you log off and on.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding the issue.

Comment: If they select a few people then save then log off and log back in it must show the people they selected previously and allow them to select some more.

Comment: So you need to save these people into a table in your database, and then select them back when they log in.  The table would have a username column to record the user who had saved the list, and a foreign key to the selected person.

Comment: Problem could be value not getting  store in database or item are not associated with database column.